# (R) Webscraping Error : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am working with the R programming language.

In a previous question ([R: Webscraping Pizza Shops - "read_html" not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73680869/r-webscraping-pizza-shops-read-html-not-working)), I learned how to scrape the names and address of Pizza Stores from YellowPages (e.g. https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/2/pizza/Canada). Here is the code for how to scrape a single page:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

scraper <- function(url) {
  page <- url %>% 
    read_html()
  
  tibble(
    name = page %>%  
      html_elements(".jsListingName") %>% 
      html_text2(),
    address = page %>% 
      html_elements(".listing__address--full") %>% 
      html_text2()
  )
}
```

I then tried to make a LOOP that will repeat this for all 391 pages:

[image]

```
a = "https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/"

b = "/pizza/Canada"

list_results = list()

for (i in 1:391)

{

url_i = paste0(a,i,b)

s_i = data.frame(scraper(url_i))

ss_i = data.frame(i,s_i)

print(ss_i)
list_results[[i]] <- ss_i


}

final = do.call(rbind.data.frame, list_results)
```

**My Problem:** I noticed that after the 60th page, I get the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(i, s_i) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
In addition: Warning message:
In for (i in seq_along(specs)) { :
  closing unused connection
```

To investigate, I went to the 60th page (https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/60/pizza/Canada) and noticed that you can not click beyond this page:

[image]

**My Question:** Is there something that I can do differently to try and move past the 60th page, or is there some internal limitation within YellowPages that is preventing from me scraping further?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limit in the Yellow Pages preventing to continue to the next page. A solution is to assign the return value of `scraper` and check the number of rows. If it is 0, break the `for` loop.

```
a = "https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/"
b = "/pizza/Canada"
list_results <- list()

for (i in 1:391) {
  url_i = paste0(a,i,b)
  
  s <- scraper(url_i, i)
  message(paste("page number:", i, "\trows:", nrow(s)))
  if(nrow(s) > 0L) {
    s_i <- as.data.frame(s)
    ss_i <- data.frame(i, s_i)
  } else {
    message("empty page, bailing out...")
    break
  }
  list_results[[i]] <- ss_i
}

final <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, list_results)
dim(final)
# [1] 2100    3
```

Comment: @ Rui Barradas: Thank you for your answer! Thank you for confirming this!

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73696551/r-webscraping-error-arguments-imply-differing-number-of-rows Thank you so much!