# R: Webscraping Pizza Shops - Adding Phone Numbers?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am working with the R programming language.

I trying to scrape the name, address and phone numbers of the pizza stores on this website :

- https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/2/pizza/Canada
- https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/2/pizza/Canada
- https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/3/pizza/Canada
- https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/4/pizza/Canada
- etc.

Using the answer provided here ([R: Webscraping Pizza Shops - "read_html" not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73680869/r-webscraping-pizza-shops-read-html-not-working)), I learned how to write the following function to perform this task:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

scraper <- function(url) {
  page <- url %>% 
    read_html()
  
  tibble(
    name = page %>%  
      html_elements(".jsListingName") %>% 
      html_text2(),
    address = page %>% 
      html_elements(".listing__address--full") %>% 
      html_text2()
  )
}

scraper("https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/2/pizza/Canada")
```

**Now, I would like to include the phone number for each of these pizza shops.**

Looking at the source code of this website, I see that this information is included within a `<h4>` tag:

[image]

But I am not sure how I can include this specification in the existing webscraping code.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward.  The key is to perform the parsing in two steps.  First find the parent node for each business then extract out the phone number.

```
library(rvest)

page<-read_html("https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/2/pizza/Canada")
#get the individual business card
nodes <- page %>% html_elements("div.listing_right_section")
#find the phone number node
phone <-  nodes %>% html_element("ul h4") %>% html_text()
```

In this case the phone numbers are within a "h4" tag underneath an "ul" tag.

*Update*
Incorporating the above code into your code:

```
scraper <- function(url) {
   page <- url %>% read_html(url)
   
   #find the business records nodes
   businesses <- page %>% html_elements("div.listing_right_section")
   
   #now extract the request information from each node
   tibble(
      name = businesses %>% html_element(".jsListingName") %>% html_text2(),
      address = businesses %>% html_element(".listing__address--full") %>% html_text2(),
      phone =  businesses %>% html_element("ul h4") %>% html_text()
   )
}

name_address = scraper("https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/2/pizza/Canada")
```

The **key for successful scraping** is to use `html_elements()` to grab all of the parent nodes, each of which contain a full record.  Then use `html_element()` (without the s) to grab the wanted field (child node) out of each parent node.
This will always work. Using html_elements will provide vectors with a variable number of elements if there is some missing information.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I tried to incorporate your code into the existing code (see answer below). Have I done this correctly? Thank you so much!